# Регулярные выражения: проверка на наличие /, "", точки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо написать одно или несколько регулярных выражений для проверки строки на наличие /, "", точки.  Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if re.search(r'[/".]', string):
    #do smth
```